# Generate 200 data points drawn from a multivariate normal distribution with mean μ and covariance matrix S, where

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, pca

[image: where mean and covarance matrix =:]

```
import numpy as np
   from numpy import sin, cos, pi
   from matplotlib.pyplot import *
   rng = np.random.default_rng(42) 
   N = 200
   center = 10, 15
   sigmas = 10, 2
   theta = 20 / 180 * pi  
   # covariance matrix
   rotmat = np.array([[cos(theta), -sin(theta)],[sin(theta), cos(theta)]])
   diagmat = np.diagflat(sigmas)
   mean =np.array([−1,−2,−3])
   # covar = rotmat @ diagmat @ rotmat.T
   covar= np.array([[2, 2 ,0],[2 ,3, 1],[0, 1 ,19]])
   print('covariance matrix:')
   print(covar)`enter code here`
   eigval, eigvec = np.linalg.eigh(covar)
   print(f'eigenvalues: {eigval}\neigenvectors:\n{eigvec}')
   print('angle of eigvector corresponding to larger eigenvalue:',
      180 /pi * np.arctan2(eigvec[1,1], eigvec[0,1]))

    # PCA
mean = data.mean(axis=0)
print('mean:', mean)
# S1: explicit sum
S1 = np.zeros((2,2), dtype=float)
print(len(data))
for i in range(len(data)):
  S1 += np.outer(data[i] - mean, data[i] - mean)
S1 /= len(data)
print(f'S1= (explicit sum)\n{S1}')
# S2: 
S2 = np.cov(data, rowvar=False, bias=True)
print(f'S2= (np.cov)\n{S2}')
# PCA:
lambdas, u = np.linalg.eigh(S2)
print(f'\nPCA\nlambda={lambdas}\nu=\n{u}')
u1 = u[:,1] # largest
print('u1=\n',u1)
print(f'first principal component angle: {180/pi*np.arctan2(u1[1], u1[0])}')
```

[image: got error]
after that I need to Perform PCA on the above data to one principal component and two principal components. What is the fractional explained variance in this two
cases

Comment: You passed `center` to `rng.multivariate_normal(...)`.  That should be `mean`, not `center`.

Comment: Please post your relevant code (with correct indentation) and error message here as *text*, *not* as image.

Comment: related code just scroll below start from import NumPy   and ends with print(f'fractional explained variance: {var_explained}'),Now ,I want to Plot the first two principal components of the data in a 2d scatter plot. What are the axes? Verify numerically that the mean squared distance between the reconstructed points and the original data (the measured remaining variance) is close to the value expected from the total variance of the data and the explained variance ratio of the first two principal components.

Comment: Again, please post your relevant code explicitly here as *text* (`print(f'fractional explained variance: {var_explained}')` is nowhere to be seen - and where does `rng.multivariate_normal` come from?); since you are using randomly generated data, this is a perfect case for a [mre]. And please do not use the comments space for adding info and clarifications - edit & update your post, if necessary.

Comment: # PCA
mu = data.mean(axis=0)
print('mean:', mu)
# S1: explicit sum
S1 = np.zeros((2,2), dtype=float)
print(len(data))
for i in range(len(data)):
  S1 += np.outer(data[i] - mu, data[i] - mu)
S1 /= len(data)
print(f'S1= (explicit sum)\n{S1}')
# S2: 
S2 = np.cov(data, rowvar=False, bias=True)
print(f'S2= (np.cov)\n{S2}')
# PCA:
lambdas, u = np.linalg.eigh(S2)
print(f'\nPCA\nlambda={lambdas}\nu=\n{u}')
u1 = u[:,1] # largest
print('u1=\n',u1)
print(f'first principal component angle: {180/pi*np.arctan2(u1[1], u1[0])}')

Comment: Please do **not** post code in the comments - it is literally unreadable! Edit & update your post instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For generating the data, you need two tricks:

- Compute a "square root" of covariance matrix S using eigenvalue-eigenvector factorization
- Use the standard formula for generating a random normal with given mean and covariance.  With Numpy it works on vectors (quoting from help(np.random.randn)):

```
For random samples from :math:`N(\mu, \sigma^2)`, use:

``sigma * np.random.randn(...) + mu``
```

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Part 1: generating random normal data with the given mean and covariance
N = 200

# covariance matrix
S = np.array([[2, 2, 0], [2, 3, 1], [0, 1, 19]])

# mean
mu = np.array([[-1, -2, -3]]).T

# get "square root" of covariance matrix via eigenfactorization
w, v = np.linalg.eig(S)
sigma = np.sqrt(w) * v

# ready, set, go!
A = sigma @ np.random.randn(3, N) + mu

print(f'sample covariance:\n{np.cov(A)}')

# sample covariance:
# [[ 1.70899164  1.74288639  0.21190326]
#  [ 1.74288639  2.59595547  1.2822817 ]
#  [ 0.21190326  1.2822817  22.04077608]]

print(f'sample mean:\n{A.mean(axis=1)}')

# sample mean:
# [-1.02385787 -1.87783415 -2.96077204]

# --------------------------------------------
# Part 2: principal component analysis on random data A

# estimate the sample covariance
R = np.cov(A)
# do the PCA
lam, u = np.linalg.eig(R)

# fractional explained variance is the relative magnitude of
# the accumulated eigenvalues

# reorder the eigenvalues & vectors with hottest eigenvalues first
col_order = np.argsort(lam)[::-1]
lam = lam[col_order]
u = u[:, col_order]

print(f'eigenvalues: {lam}')
# eigenvalues: [22.13020272  3.87946467  0.3360558 ]

var_explained = lam.cumsum() / lam.sum()
print(f'fractional explained variance: {var_explained}')
# fractional explained variance: [0.83999223 0.98724439 1.        ]
#                                  ^^ 84% in first dimension alone,
#                                     99% in first two dimensions

# do the projection
B = u.T @ A

# now the variance in B is concentrated in the first two dimensions
covariance after PCA projection:
[[ 2.21302027e+01 -2.68545720e-15 -1.60675493e-15]
 [-2.68545720e-15  3.87946467e+00 -1.19613978e-15]
 [-1.60675493e-15 -1.19613978e-15  3.36055802e-01]]

# scatter plot
plt.plot(B[0], B[1], '.')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.grid('on')
plt.xlabel('principal axis 0')
plt.ylabel('principal axis 1')
plt.title('Random data projected onto two principal axes')


# project back using ONLY a two dimensional subspace of B
#  i.e. drop the last eigenvector
A_approx = u[:,:2] @ B[:2,:]

# error analysis
err3 = A - A_approx
mse = (err3**2).sum(axis=0).mean()

print(f'predicted error variance: {lam[-1]}')
print(f'measured error variance: {mse}')
# predicted error variance: 0.3360558019705344
# measured error variance: 0.41137559916273914
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @AbbeGily what if I want to Plot the first two principal components of the data in a 2d scatter plot. What
are the axes?
Verify numerically that the mean squared distance between the reconstructed points and the original data (the measured remaining variance)
is close to the value expected from the total variance of the data and the
explained variance ratio of the first two principal components.

Comment: @Mohammed the response is updated to include the projection (with scatter plot), the reverse projection from 2-dimensional subspace, and error analysis

Comment: That is really cool thanks